# Unable to Pip Install PyMeenus using local package

Tags: python, installation, pip

I tried to run pip install on a local package for PyMeenus, and encountered below error. I'm on Python 3.9.

Anyone knows how I can overcome this? Thanks.

```
(base) test@test-c161616e-0:/notebooks/pypi_envs$ pip install PyMeeus-0.5.11.tar.gz
```

Processing ./PyMeeus-0.5.11.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /opt/conda/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-m2fwwivg/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-m2fwwivg/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-98jdihbo
cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-m2fwwivg/
Complete output (11 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 20, in 
from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in 
from setuptools.depends import Require
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in 
from .py33compat import Bytecode
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 55, in 
unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///notebooks/pypi_envs/PyMeeus-0.5.11.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+HTMLParser+object+has+no+attribute+unescape

Comment: The error seems to be a bug in `setuptools`. Try to upgrade `setuptools`. Or use Python 3.8.